# Unable to apply jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a page **`searchKB.jsp`** and it has some code like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {app:app,env:env,ptitle:ptitle,kbaseId:kbaseId},
    url : 'jsp/knowledgeBase/kbResults.jsp',
    success: function(res){
        getResponse(res);
    },
    error: function(){
        document.getElementById("message").style.display="";
        $('#message').html("<b><font color=red face=Arial size=2>An Error encountered while processing your Request.Please try again after sometime.</font></b>");
    }
});
function getResponse(response){
    document.getElementById("message").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("KBInfo").innerHTML = response;
}
```

`searchKB.jsp`is calling **`kbResults.jsp`** through the above code and now i want to apply **jquery on elements of**  **`kbResults.jsp`** ..how will i do this ?

i tried everything but it is failing

`<input type="button" id="expand3" value="Hide"/>    <div id="result3">hide this</div>`

and corresponding jquery code

`$("#expand3").click(function(){
    $("#result3").hide();
     });`

Comment: What do you mean by "apply jquery" ?

Comment: You should first append kbResults.jsp somewhere in the dom.

Comment: i mean i want to use `hide()` and other functions

Comment: @nikhil i didnt get u

Comment: If you want to hide the newly added html then you can do something like $('#KBInfo').hide(); $('#KBInfo').html(response);

Comment: @amolsingh - Please ignore my previous comment. What kind of jquery events you want to execute?

Comment: I believe you are experiencing this issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816486/cant-get-div-content-from-jquery-object-after-ajax-request If you are populating the page with new code via js, you need to use the `on` function or the ajax success setting: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that elements with IDs `expand3` and `result3` are coming from that AJAX call, you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {app:app,env:env,ptitle:ptitle,kbaseId:kbaseId},
    url : 'jsp/knowledgeBase/kbResults.jsp',
    success: function(res){
        getResponse(res);
    } // removed the error callback for clarity
});
function getResponse(response){
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#KBInfo").html(response);

    // only then attach the listener
    // because #expand3 needs to be in the DOM
    $("#expand3").click(function(){
        $("#result3").hide();
    });
}
```

Or, you can use @ashokd's solution with delegated listener.

Comment: I'm glad I could help... although I'm pretty sure @ashold's solution should work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try using something like this.

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#expand3", function(){
    $("#result3").hide();
});
```

Comment: @amolsingh Does click event get fired?

Comment: i got your point ashok but i am trying to use in some another ..but thnks , i learned a lot from this fiddle :)